# Yank lines from one file in vi ( not vim ) to another?

Tags: copy, vi, paste

I'm used to VIM and usually I split screen with  and open another file, yank the text into the second one. However I'm dealing with a legacy server which only has vi, how could I either open multiple files with it if it doesn't support split views or copy text from one file to another ( 2 separate vim instances I guess ).

I don't think this server has 'screen' enabled and I have limited access so I can't just go installing things.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

open one file in Vi, yank text, then use

:e another_file

to open another file, and paste.

Comment: wow, how silly of me. I got too used to split view that I just forgot about everything else.. soo obvious.. thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are already inside a file where you have to paste text.

- :w (first save the current content)
- :e file2
- goto location and yank (say yy)
- :b 1 (goto buffer 1, i.e. return back to original file)
- goto location and paste (p)

Answer (score -2):

good one. if you want to yank say some 100 lines, you have to type first '100' and then 'yy'.

Comment: irrelevant to the question